# pulseaudio recording feedback

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

When I rebuild pulseaudio (need to create a plugin) I have a bad speaker.monitor. It added null samples after each stop of a aplay command?

Then the microphone are not anymore synchonous.

I did not understand why it does this kink of things?

Note. it work with native pulseaudio, but not with

- mainstream pulseaudio repository #5.0
- pulseaudio 4.0
- ubuntu package sources + patch (that not compile)

Ubuntu comilation error of ubuntu package with patches:

```
.libs/module_alsa_card_la-module-alsa-card.o: In function `module_alsa_card_LTX_pa__init':
src/modules/alsa/module-alsa-card.c:757: undefined reference to `pa_alsa_extcon_new'
.libs/module_alsa_card_la-module-alsa-card.o: In function `module_alsa_card_LTX_pa__done':
src/modules/alsa/module-alsa-card.c:824: undefined reference to `pa_alsa_extcon_free'
```

command terminal 1:

```
parecord --no-remix --no-remap --device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" --file-format=wav ~/aaaa_lundi_record_spk.wav
```

command terminal 2:

```
parecord --no-remix --no-remap --device="alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" --file-format=wav ~/aaaa_lundi_record_mic.wav
```

command terminal 3:

```
paplay  xxx.wav
```